# Which term is used to describe functions with multiple “modes”?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

[Clojure's range function](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/range), for example, has four modes:

> ```
> Usage: (range)
>        (range end)
>        (range start end)
>        (range start end step)
>
> Returns a lazy seq of nums from start (inclusive) to end
> (exclusive), by step, where start defaults to 0, step to 1, and end
> to infinity.
> ```

Is there an adjective to describe such functions?

Comment: Could be called overloaded too.

Comment: Ah, yes! You should add that as an answer, @leppie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they're referred to as **arity-overloaded** functions, whereas variadic functions take an unbounded number of arguments.

http://clojure.org/functional_programming

> Clojure supports *arity overloading* in a single function object, self-reference, and variable-arity functions using &

Answer (score 3):

I'd call them multi-arity or arity-overloaded, on the understanding that a variadic overload is to be thought of as a single separate arity overload.